# lubridate::duration("minutes") returns an error when duration less than 60 seconds

Tags: r, lubridate

I am timing events that are usually of multiple minutes duration but occasionally an event will be less than 60 seconds and lubridate::duration() returns an erroneous value.

I can fix this problem with an IF and 2 duration functions by checking for time differences greater than or less than 60 seconds but it seems such an inelegant method.

```
library(lubridate)
for (x in c(59, 60)) {
  startTime <- Sys.time()
Sys.sleep(x)
print(duration(as.numeric(Sys.time() - startTime), "minutes" ))
}

[1] "3543.86645793915s (~59.06 minutes)"
[1] "60.0540399551392s (~1 minutes)"
```

I just want time less than 60 seconds in decimal minutes or just seconds.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am supposing your interval of time are objects of class difftime. If it is like that, see the next script:

```
#Create object difftime
a <- Sys.time()
b <- Sys.time()
DELTA_TIME <- b - a
#print the duration
print(duration(as.numeric(DELTA_TIME,units='mins'),units='minutes'))
```

See that this way of printing the duration will accept any object of class difftime. The important thing is the argument unit='mins' in the function as.numeric

Comment: I am presuming you meant ```time_span``` rather than ```time_spam``` but ```time_span``` throws an error: ```Error in duration(as.numeric(time_span, units = "mins"), units = "minutes") : 
  object 'time_span' not found```. Is there a package I should install?

Comment: Sorry, it was the object I named DELTA_TIME, I copy it from a try in my computer and I named in another way. I already edited the answer

Comment: I should have spotted that. Thanks.